# Python receive message streaming

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

```
# part
def my():
    while True:
        a = input("message  :")
        a1 = s.send(str.encode(a))
        a2 = bytes.decode(s.recv(1024))
        print(" The received message : ",a2)
```

Hi, My question is how can I make the client receive the message directly from the server while the user can input a message at the same time? 
because there are many messages that is received from the server and merge together.

Comment: You will have to use threads or an asynchronous framework like asyncio or twisted.

Comment: I don't think you can do this nicely on the command line, even with threads. Suppose you start typing "Hello how are you?" and your friend sends you "what's up". Then the command prompt will look like "message : He The received message : what's up llo how are you?"

Comment: Yes I know that but if I got many message from the server how can I spilt it out?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it:

- Use one of the functions from the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select) module, e.g.
  [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select), [`select.poll()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll.poll). These functions allow
  you to check a set of file descriptors (including those of sockets)
  for I/O events - readable, writable, error. Your code responds to these
  events by reading or writing as appropriate.
- Use a framework that supports asynchronous I/O, e.g. [`asynccore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore)
  which is in the Python standard library. Or 3rd party ones such as
  twisted, tornado, etc.
- Use threads. Have one thread to handle I/O with the user, and a
  second (or more) thread to handle each network connection.

A detailed description of each of these methods is beyond the scope of SO, but feel free to ask further questions about specifics details or problems that you have.